# AndroidStudio disable "Expected resource of type string"

Tags: android, android-studio, butterknife

I've just tried to generate signed apk for one of my projects (I already did this before), but (maybe since updating Android Studio) I'm getting

> Error:Error: Expected resource of type string [ResourceType]

This is because I'm using Butterknife's @BindString, that is generated into something like that

```
target.settings = res.getString(2131230792);
```

How can I make studio not detect this as error? I've tried searching in settings, but without success.

Comment: I've been using butterknife for a while now, and this didn't appear until I started messing with product flavors in my gradle file.

Comment: Android Studio never runs out of stuff that cause developer headaches

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is reported [on the GitHub project](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/338).
It will be fixed in the next version of ButterKnife.

The workaround is indicated [there](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/338#issuecomment-141208551), and is to add a `lint.xml` file on the `app` module with the following content to ignore that errors on `*$$ViewBinder` classes (the ones that ButterKnife generates):

```
<issue id="ResourceType">
    <!-- Remove this when this is fixed: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/338 -->
    <ignore path="**/*$$ViewBinder.java" />
</issue>
```

Comment: The accepted answer blindly turns off all ResourceType lint checks for your module, exposing your codebase to potentially more bugs, while this answer specifically targets the generated classes that cause the issue. This is why I prefer this answer.

Answer (score 66):

Answer to this is: disable lint rule in your build.gradle

```
android {
  lintOptions {
    disable "ResourceType"
  }
}
```

Edit:
This may happen particularly when migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a better solution is to temporary disable error/warning by using `@SuppressLint("ResourceType")` just before the method definition.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Check [answer] for tips on giving good answers to questions here.  Specifically there are ways to format code snips so they show as code rather than plain text.  Also, in general it's best to focus on newer questions without well accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

I has a similar problem. with a getString method. Turned out i was trying to get the string value not from strings.xml but from ids.xml, because i was getting it with getString(R.id.MYSTRING), when it should be R.string.MYSTRING

Answer (score -1):

this is for some Views by same id and u try to change some property for one of them.
When try to generate apk android find some confilict about resours id

**To solve that**

better way find the code and try solve that from another way to your purpose

GoodLuck