# Android Studio: Error Expected Resources as string when using R.color.colorX

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to assign a color from my colors.xml file to the my `tableLayout` with the following code:

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.color.colorMain)));
```

But I get an error: **"Expected resource of type string..."**
I have tried different things from other threads
1. Changed my **minSdkVersion** in gradle and Android Studio to 23
2. Tried to disable lint rule in your build.gradle discribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009832/androidstudio-disable-expected-resource-of-type-string).

None of them worked and I still get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorMain)));
```

or try

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor(getResources().getColor(getResources(), R.color.colorMain, null)));
```

Comment: None of them works for me. I get an error message: parsColor(java.lang.String)in Color cannot be applied to (int).